# right way to move large objects between folders/buckets in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to move some large file(s) (1 terabyte to 5 terabyte) from one S3 location to a different directory in the same bucket or to a different bucket.

There are few ways that I can think of doing it more robustly.

1. Trigger a lambda function based on ObjectCreated:Put trigger and use boto3 to copy the file to new location and delete source file. Plain and simple. But if there is any error while copying the files, I lose the event. I have to design some sort of tracking system along with this.
2. Use same-region-replication and delete the source once the replication is completed. I do not think there is any event emitted once the object is replicated so I am not sure.
3. Trigger a Step function and have Copy and Delete as separate steps. This way if for some reason Copy or Delete steps fail, I can rerun the state machine. Here again the problem is what if the file size is too big for lambda to copy?
4. Trigger a lambda function based on `ObjectCreated:Put` trigger and create a data pipeline and move the file using `aws s3 mv`. This can get little expensive.

What is the right way of doing this to make this reliable?

*I am looking for advise on the right approach. I am not looking for code. Please do not post `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 mv` or `aws s3api copy-object` one line commands.*

Comment: Is this a one-off requirement, or an on-going requirement? That is, do all the objects already exist, or do you want the copy to happen when new objects are created in the future? Please note that S3 Replication only triggers when objects are created -- it won't work for existing objects. Also, are you comfortable with writing code that involves multi-part copies?

Comment: It’s an on-going solution. As new objects are uploaded, it should copy and delete. I can write code in shell and Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation appears to be:

- New objects are being created in Bucket A
- You wish to 'move' them to Bucket B (or move them to a different location in Bucket A)
- The move should happen immediately after object creation

The simplest solution, of course, would be to create the objects in the correct location without needing to move them. I will assume you have a reason for not being able to do this.

To respond to your concepts:

- **Using an AWS Lambda function:** This is the easiest and most-responsive method. The code would need to do a multi-part copy since the objects can be large. If there is an unrecoverable error, the original object would be left in the source bucket for later retry.
- **Using same-region replication:** This is a much easier way to copy the objects to a desired destination. S3 could push the object creation information to an Amazon SQS queue, which could be consulted for later deletion of the source object. You are right that timing would be slightly tricky. If you are fine with keeping some of the source files around for a while, the queue could be processed at regular intervals (eg every 15 minutes).
- **Using a Step Function:** You would need something to trigger the Step Function (another Lambda function?). This is probably overkill since the first option (using Lambda) could delete the source object after a successful copy, without needing to invoke a subsequent step. However, Step Functions might be able to provide some retry functionality.
- **Use Data Pipeline:** Don't. Enough said.

Using an AWS Lambda function to copy an object would require it to send a Copy command for each part of an object, thereby performing a multi-part copy. This can be made faster by running multiple requests in parallel through multiple threads. (I haven't tried that in Lambda, but it should work.)

Such multi-threading has already been implemented in the AWS CLI. So, another option would be to **trigger an AWS Lambda function (#1 above) that calls out to run the AWS CLI `aws s3 mv` command**. Yes, this is possible, see: [How to use AWS CLI within a Lambda function (aws s3 sync from Lambda) :: Ilya Bezdelev](https://bezdelev.com/hacking/aws-cli-inside-lambda-layer-aws-s3-sync/). The benefit of this method is that the code already exists, it works, using `aws s3 mv` will delete the object after it is successfully copied, and it will run very fast because the AWS CLI implements multi-part copying in parallel.

Comment: the problem I see with multi-part upload is that first I have to first download the file.  Also downloading 3 terabyte file using lambda will not work due to storage constraint. This also may not be cost effective. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Not quite. You can do "multi-part **copy**", where each part comes from an existing part in S3. So, you're simply telling S3 to copy a part of one object to a part of a new object. It's the only way to copy large objects, and you'll see that the AWS CLI does it that way too. See: [Copying an object using multipart upload - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CopyingObjctsMPUapi.html)